# Does one say "subscribe to insurance" or is "enroll" or "buy" a more fitting verb?

Tags: verbs, collocation

This is for use in an apartment lease. The lease is translated from Japanese for reference only for expats living in Japan, and will not be legally binding.

"The Second Party shall, for the duration of the validity of The Agreement, **subscribe to the insurance** defined separately ..."

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is *purchase*.

Comment: I'd either get a lawyer or use a recognized standard form, but if you would rather use the web: I would try _purchase and maintain_ to make clear that the insurance must be kept in force.

Comment: Why not just *buy* insurance? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buy+insurance%2C+take+insurance%2C+purchase+insurance%2C+buy+a+policy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuy%20insurance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20insurance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurchase%20insurance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20a%20policy%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "have, maintain, apply for, arrange, buy, get, obtain, purchase, take out ..." (Orpheus Technology, ProWritingAid at  http://prowritingaid.com/collocations-dictionary/insurance/Collocations-of-insurance.aspx )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Subscribe" seems a rather odd word to use with respect to insurance, though I think its meaning is plain, and when it comes to legal documents often words take on special meanings and I'm not a lawyer.

It isn't clear from your question if you are trying to interpret a lease or write a lease. When writing a legal document you might consider the assistance of a lawyer since courts often attach special meaning to particular words.

If you are trying to interpret the language, one meaning of "subscribe" is "arrange to receive something regularly", and for a renewing lease you might be required to subscribe to insurance, to ensure that it is regularly renewed.

If you are going for clarity I'd simply say:

The Second Party shall ***have insurance (defined separately)***, for the duration of the validity of The Agreement....

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. I am translating a lease from Japanese to English, for use by English-speakers residing in Japan.

Comment: As a point of interest, though not by way of an answer to the OP's question, the word 'subscribe' is very much aligned with Insurance, much of which operates on a 'subscription' model. The word 'subscribe' in that case has exactly the same meaning as 'underwrite'; sub=under, scribe=write and derives from a time when the companies covering risk would add their names to the bottom of the policy, literally to *under* *write*...

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have pointed out, for legally binding terms consult a lawyer. In the legal profession words can have specific, unusual meanings.

That said, in common usage insurance is said to be **purchased** (or **bought**). In English usage insurance as if it were a physical object of limited shelf-life, like food. It doesn't make much sense, but that's how it is.

So people can be heard to say: *"you must purchase insurance"*, or *"I have been buying insurance for three years"*, or *"I stopped buying insurance"*.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. I have update the original post to indicate that this translation is for reference only, and the legally binding version remains in Japanese.